# Restart tor through command line

Tags: unix, command-line, proxy, tor

I am using the `tor-request` node module for tor and after brew install I did:

`tor &`

(Which runs as background process)

Now that its running in the background, i adjusted some torr settings and want to reset it. How would I do that? Thanks! I searched everywhere I tried some things with no luck. When I try to run `tor &` I get this:

```
Jul 17 17:15:48.699 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Jul 17 17:15:48.700 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc".
Jul 17 17:15:48.704 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jul 17 17:15:48.704 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Jul 17 17:15:48.704 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Jul 17 17:15:48.704 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Jul 17 17:15:48.705 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Jul 17 17:15:48.705 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Comment: You can type the command `fg` to bring the job to the foreground and then use control-c to kill it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a

```
kill -HUP $(pidof tor)
```

Tor will reset itself and read the new configuration.

It might be better to use zhe control protocol. Using this you can send your configuration directly to the Tor process.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill your background process with the following command:

```
kill $!
```

$! is the PID of the last process run in the background. If this didn't work you can search for the process using:

```
ps -eaf | grep tor
```

That should return any PIDs of running Tor processes, which you can then use with `kill`. Once Tor was killed you can just start it again.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I tried that but it threw this: `kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]` I also tried `kill -9 [PID}` which i read somewhere. (Ive never used kill)

Comment: `kill` takes a process ID as parameter and tries to end it. I updated my answer with a second way to find the process, hopefully that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can kill tor like this

```
sudo killall -HUP tor
```